# How to connect to SQL Server database from Delphi FireMonkey

Tags: android, sql-server, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I want to connect to MS SQL Server to insert or update some data with FireMonkey for my Android app, I'm using Delphi xe8.
Is there any way to do this with default component? Not using other component.
I'm using the remote server over ID address.

Comment: Um, yes. Via the standard FireDAC components. It's [covered in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Database_Connectivity_%28FireDAC%29)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use XML/JSON services to connect SQL Server database. It will save your time, data security, app security and application development time.

Indy components are great for Http Rio, also you can create your soap connection objects directly from code too. *It depends on your choices.*

Also you can connect databases from FireMonkey directly using FireDAC components. It can be useful for SQLite database but I never used FireDAC for SQL Server connections.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you don't access a remote database directly from your device like we do in desktop applications.

I suggest you do a request to a web service, include all parameters for insert/update and web service do the job for you.